# something wrong with mount in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, mount, gentoo

I install Gentoo as a virtual machine in VirtualBox and I use Windows 8 as the host. I share a disk in my windows system and I use mount.cifs in Gentoo to mount the disk.

Everything seems fine. But when I leave the virtual machine and do something in windows for a while, I found that there is something wrong with the mounted disk.

For example, I mount the shared disk to /home/abc/data. With some time spent in windows, I return to work in Gentoo. When I change my work directory to /home/abc, and use the command ls, it never returns(no output at all and the prompt line never comes back). And Ctrl-C does nothing in this situation. Even if I am the root of the machine.

The only thing I can do is to halt the machine. However, when I use the command halt, it warns me that it "Failed to simply unmount filesystems", and no output after that line. I have to close the VirtualBox window to power off the machine.

Could someone tell me why this situation happens and what should I do to avoid it??? Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe the same as this [Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/307636/virtualbox-running-fedora-15-keeps-losing-its-cifs-mount-of-a-windows-share).